# AttributeError: 'S3' object has no attribute 'Bucket'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

What I'm doing wrong?

```
class S3:
    def __init__(self, b: str, r: str = ""):
        self._bucket = b
        self._remote_dir = r
        self._s3 = client("s3")


def get_bootcamp_dumps(self, file_name):
try:
    my_bucket = self._s3.Bucket(self._bucket)
    dumps_list = []

    for object in my_bucket.objects.all():
        dumps_list.append(object.key)
    filtered_list = [i for i in dumps_list if i.startswith(file_name)]
    return filtered_list
except ClientError as error:
    print(error)
```

and this is how I'm calling it

```
s3 = S3(b='my_bucket_name')

dump_list=s3.get_bootcamp_dumps('key_word')
```

and I'm getting this error

**AttributeError: 'S3' object has no attribute 'Bucket'**

Comment: What is `S3` and where is it defined?

Comment: @AnonCoward it is defined under my class S3

class S3:
    def __init__(self, b: str, r: str = ""):
        self._bucket = b
        self._remote_dir = r
        self._s3 = client("s3")

Comment: Look at the [example in the docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#bucket). You need the s3 resource, rather than s3 client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

boto3 has two different ways to access Amazon S3. It appears that you are mixing usage between the two of them.

#### Client Method

Using a **client** maps 1:1 with an AWS API call. For example:

```py
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

objects = s3_client.list_objects('bucket-name')

for object in objects['Contents']:
  print(object['Key'])
```

#### Resource Method

boto3 also provides more convenient 'resource' methods, which are more Pythonic. For example:

```py
import boto3

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

for object in s3_resource.Bucket('bucket-name').objects.all():
  print(object.key)
```

Comment: thanks @John you are absolutely right. I was mixing resources.